# MVC3 Roles Dropdown box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, selectlistitem

Im trying add roles to a drop dropdown box but im getting the error thats below. please help.

Model Code

```
  public SelectListItem RolesForUser {get; set;}
```

Controller Code

```
 var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.username);
 model.RolesForUser=roles.select(m => new SelectListItem() 
 {Value=m.ToString(),Text=m.ToString()});
```

Error   21  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: pubic IEnumerable<SelectlistItem> roles is the code im surpose to have in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare RolesForUser as `List<SelectListItem> RolesForUser` and change LINQ query as

```
model.RolesForUser=roles.select(m => new SelectListItem() {Value=m.ToString(),Text=m.ToString()}).ToList();
```

Comment: Or just a `SelectList`, that is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` :)